# How to make a chain of nginx proxies using nginx docker containers with each docker having different IP?

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, proxy, docker-network

I have a django app. In front of that I want to setup 3 nginx proxies (docker containers) in local (MacOS) like:

browser-->proxy1-->proxy2-->proxy3-->(gunicorn):django-app

I have to check some IP related thing in my django app. So when I am logging the `x_forwarded_for` header in my django app I am getting it as: `'X-Forwarded-For': '172.17.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 172.17.0.1'`

I want to give each of my nginx proxy container a different static IP. How to do that. What docker command I need to use ?